# Detect a file mimeType which is being uploaded

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express to handle file uploads, but the problem is client is unable to set mimeType, so for example if `client is sending .3gp file` it will come as `123 for an example`, does not come with any mimeType, I have looked into express req object but no luck for `automatic mimeType`, is there any possibility for looking up `mimeType of files being uploaded`.

Is there any possibility to detect mimeType using ffmpeg or avconv or HandBrake-CLI?

Comment: There's middleware for that -> https://github.com/broofa/node-mime

Comment: @adeneo Thanks a ton, it works great. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @adeneo I am sorry, that is working on only files with mimeType set while posting from client.

Answer (score 0):

There is [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic) which is a binding to libmagic (the same library the `file` command uses).

Comment: not mmmagic's fault, because I see the same thing with the `file` command, but it seems the MIME type of a lot of different video formats including 3gp isn't detected.